# NGINX Remove index.php /index.php/something/more/ to /something/more

Tags: nginx, php

I'm trying to clean urls in NGINX using framework DooPHP.

This =>
- http://example.com/index.php/something/more/
To This =>
- http://example.com/something/more/

I want to remove (clean url) the "index.php" from the url if someone try to enter in the first form. Like a permanent redirect.

How to do this config on NGINX?

Thanks.

[Update: Actual nginx config]

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name vip.example.com;
  rewrite ^/(.*) https://vip.example.com/$1 permanent;
}

server {
       listen 443;
       server_name vip.example.com;

       error_page 404 /vip.example.com/404.html;
       error_page 403 /vip.example.com/403.html;
       error_page 401 /vip.example.com/401.html;
       location /vip.example.com {
           root /sites/errors;
       }

       ssl on;
       ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/config/server.csr;
       ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/config/server.sky;

       if (!-e $request_filename){
           rewrite /.* /index.php;
       }

       location / {
           auth_basic  "example Team Access";
           auth_basic_user_file  config/htpasswd;
           root   /sites/vip.example.com;
           index  index.php;
       }

       location ~ \.php$ {
           fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
           fastcgi_index  index.php;
           fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /sites/vip.example.com$fastcgi_script_name;
           include        fastcgi_params;
           fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
      }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

This was the line I was looking for, I did it my self. I could have some bugs.

What do you think?

```
server {

 ....

  rewrite ^/index.php/(.*) /$1  permanent;

 ....

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've try it on CodeIgniter 1.7 & 2.0, and i change

config.php `$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI";`

and i add `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?r=$request_uri;`

on nginx.conf, and worked

```
location / {
       auth_basic  "example Team Access";
       auth_basic_user_file  config/htpasswd;
       root   /sites/vip.example.com;
       index  index.php;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?r=$request_uri;
   }
```

maybe it same on DooPHP

Comment: Now try requesting /index.php explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to nginx server config part.

```
location / {
                if (!-e $request_filename) {
                        rewrite ^/([^?]*)(?:\?(.*))? /index.php?title=$1&$2 last;
                }
                if ($uri ~* "\.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$") {
                        expires max;
                        break;
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line

```
if (!-e $request_filename){
   rewrite /.* /index.php;
}
```

Add this inside location /

```
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php;

    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1.php;
    }
```

Hopefully, this work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add this location object to your server configuration in your nginx.conf. If `location /` already exists, then just add the `try_files` line.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added the following rule to my NGINX config file (After the the all location rules):

```
if ($request_uri ~* "^(.*/)index\.php(.*)") {

  return 307 $1$2;

}
```

It is working fine for me.